# Ubuntu 16.04 snapd problem

Tags: 16.04, snap

I am having a problem with installing/uninstalling `snapd` and I cannot install any package.
And it shows the following error:

> error: cannot communicate with server: Posthttp://localhost/v2/snaps/code: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

This is the version I have:

```
snap --version
snap    2.31.1~14.04
snapd   unavailable
series  -
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the entire session, from your command through the failure and all of the error messages. Summaries often lack key details.

Comment: I don't really know how to explain it sorry, but i guess it's not the good version because when I exedute the commands to install a package (from the snap store) I obtain the following error :         error: cannot communicate with server: Posthttp://localhost/v2/snaps/code: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand: We're not asking you *explain* it. We're asking you to *show* us.

Comment: what to show exacty ?i ve already provided the installing error i get

Comment: The entire terminal session. Summaries often lack key details.

Comment: should I copythe hole terminal session ? how to do so please

Comment: In terminal: Highlight and copy. On AskUbuntu: Paste, then properly format.

Comment: `(xenial)root@localhost:~# snap version
snap    2.39.2ubuntu0.2
snapd   unavailable
series  -
(xenial)root@localhost:~# sudo snap install --classic code
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/code: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory `

Comment: Try reinstalling snapd: `sudo snap install --reinstall snapd`. Oh, and don't use sudo when running as root.

Comment: this is what i got `Setting up snapd (2.39.2ubuntu0.2) 
md5sum: /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine: No such file or directory`

Comment: Why did you have version 2.31.1~14.04 on a 16.04 system?  That can indicate serious problems.

Comment: what can I can do to solve it ?

Comment: Depends upon the cause. Many possible causes. Easy solution is to create a 16.04 LiveUSB, boot into the "Try Ubuntu" environment, and see if snaps install properly. If snaps install properly in the "Try Ubuntu" environment, then backup your data and replace your broken system with a clean install. If snaps don't install properly in the "Try Ubuntu" environment, then you have discovered a bug to be reported.

Comment: the problem here is I have linux running beside chromeos on a chromebook(crouton)

Comment: It makes more sense now. Seems like the problem you have is crouton: Crouton breaks snapd. You cannot use snaps in a crouton environment.